# Cassandra ERROR: Unable to create injector

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I succesfully upgraded Datastax Enterprice from 5.1.5 to 5.1.7 in two of three nodes. In the last one (mac os), I used the `.dmg` file to upgrade. After that, then i tried to start the node:

```
$ ./dse/bin/dse cassandra -s -k
```

i got this error:

```
ERROR [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:06,225  DseModule.java:97 - {}. Exiting...
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: cdc-raw directory '/var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)
```

complete log:

```
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.advanceAllocatingFrom (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Row;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/SerializationHeader;Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.indexes (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/IFilter/FilterKey;)[J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.setIndexes (JJIJ[J)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
INFO  [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:05,413  DseModule.java:90 - Loading DSE module
INFO  [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:05,708  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/Users/cass/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:06,105  YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/Users/cass/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:06,140  Config.java:509 - Node configuration:[aggregated_request_timeout_in_ms=120000; allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor=null; authenticator=com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator; authorizer=com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=640; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=64; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=/var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=dataXS; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=/Users/cass/dse/commitlog; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; continuous_paging=org.apache.cassandra.config.ContinuousPagingConfig@9caca531; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_dc_rtt_in_ms=0; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@61a88b8c; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=com.datastax.bdp.snitch.DseDelegateSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=/Users/cass/dse/hints; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=192.168.1.108; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; pick_level_on_streaming=false; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=192.168.1.108; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/Users/cass/dse/saved_caches; seed_gossip_probability=1.0; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=172.16.21.18,192.168.1.108}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@22295ec4; trickle_fsync=true; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:06,142  DatabaseDescriptor.java:353 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:06,143  DatabaseDescriptor.java:411 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 512MB
INFO  [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:06,143  DatabaseDescriptor.java:415 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 512MB
21-Feb-2018 16:59:06.175 INFO [main] com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor.visit An exception was caught and reported. Message: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: cdc-raw directory '/var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
 org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: cdc-raw directory '/var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.resolveAndCheckDirectory(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1033)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySimpleConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:444)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:296)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:127)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.<init>(DseCoreModule.java:82)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.getRequiredModules(DseModule.java:144)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.configure(AbstractDseModule.java:27)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(DseModule.java:78)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.datastax.bdp.ioc.DseInjector.get(DseInjector.java:34)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)

ERROR [main] 2018-02-21 16:59:06,225  DseModule.java:97 - {}. Exiting...
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: cdc-raw directory '/var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.bdp.ioc.DseInjector.get(DseInjector.java:34) ~[dse-core-5.1.7.jar:5.1.7]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91) ~[dse-core-5.1.7.jar:5.1.7]
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: cdc-raw directory '/var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw' or, if it does not already exist, an existing parent directory of it, is not readable and writable for the DSE. Check file system and configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.resolveAndCheckDirectory(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1033) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.1.2130.jar:3.11.1.2130]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applySimpleConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:444) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.1.2130.jar:3.11.1.2130]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.applyAll(DatabaseDescriptor.java:296) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.1.2130.jar:3.11.1.2130]
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.daemonInitialization(DatabaseDescriptor.java:127) ~[cassandra-all-3.11.1.2130.jar:3.11.1.2130]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseCoreModule.<init>(DseCoreModule.java:82) ~[dse-core-5.1.7.jar:5.1.7]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.getRequiredModules(DseModule.java:144) ~[dse-core-5.1.7.jar:5.1.7]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.AbstractDseModule.configure(AbstractDseModule.java:27) ~[dse-core-5.1.7.jar:5.1.7]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(DseModule.java:78) ~[dse-core-5.1.7.jar:5.1.7]
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Note we don't use [solved] title devices here. To accept an answer, click on the tick icon to the left of the one you prefer. Accepting your own answers is fine as well.

Comment: I can't accept my answer in the first two days.. Thats why I added SOLVED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to create the missing directory and change permissions on /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/cassandra/cdc_raw
$ sudo chown dse_user /var/lib/cassndra/cdc_raw
```

Comment: That's good to note.  Some of these directories Cassandra is capable of creating on its own, but some have to be created ahead of time.  I guess this goes on the "ahead of time" list.

Comment: How would one know which need to be created and whic won't?